# Google Sheet - Search "Cat" or "Dog" in column A then return max value of corresponding range of column B

Tags: spreadsheet

sorry if my English is not too good. I have a sheet, with data as below photo, I want to search D2 ("Cat") in A:A and then return max value on corresponding B column. Hope that you guys will help me to figure out a formula that generate the max of unique, thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAXIFS` formula. `=MAXIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,D2)` will give max value for the value in D2 column.

For documentation please refer to https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817?hl=en

Comment: hello Main, thank you so much it works like a champ !

Answer (score 1):

The best and simpliest way is to perform a pivot table[image]

the other way is

```
=arrayformula(query(A2:B6,"select A,max(B) group by A ",0))
```